# Django won't connect to postgresql after SSL certificate from let's encrypt

Tags: django, postgresql, apache, ubuntu, lets-encrypt

I recently ran certbot --apache to create a ssl certificate for my site.
however my site went down immediatley after I did so and the apache error log shows I am not connecting to postgresql.

apache error log:

```html
[Tue May 21 03:25:22.400677 2019] [wsgi:error]     connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
[Tue May 21 03:25:22.400679 2019] [wsgi:error   File "/home/kmostafa89/MK_SITE/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 130, in connect
[Tue May 21 03:25:22.400682 2019] [wsgi:error]     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
[Tue May 21 03:25:22.400684 2019] [wsgi:error][remote 81.103.75.183:56590] django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
[Tue May 21 03:25:22.400686 2019] [wsgi:error] \tIs the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
[Tue May 21 03:25:22.400689 2019] [wsgi:error]  \tTCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I tried re configuring postgresql.conf file towards the key and cert produced by the certbot but that did not resolve the issue.

any suggestion to get my site back up again would mean a lot.